# Rails Testing: Shared RSpec Data Across Files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

SO...

I am currently working on reducing my project's build time, specifically the time our test suite takes to run.

We do have some poorly written tests that are creating database objects in `let` bindings (so they get saved every test) that have the opportunity to be refactored into `before(:context)` and `after(:context)` with `let(:object) { @object.clone }`. We also have some poorly written FactoryGirl (FactoryBot now?) factories that are a bit aggressive with the objects they create (I know about `build_stubbed`) that can be improved upon.

Addressing these issues would be a step in the right direction, but I am interested in creating a more fundamental change to my team's shared testing model as many files in our system require the same core setup (i.e. many `before(:context)` blocks look the exact same).

I was thinking that it would be a great win if my team could keep `db/seeds.rb` up to date and in `rails_helper.rb` or `spec_helper.rb`, load the seeds before running the test suite and expose the core data via instance variables.

Tests would then be able to do... `let(:core_object) { @core_object.clone }` that would immediately be available to them (a bit of magic, yes). I think we would have to be quite careful with these instance variable names as well to ensure they don't conflict with individual file instance variables.

I was wondering if anyone else has attempted something similar or has any suggestions on how to further DRY up my team's common test setup, thanks.

Comment: eventhough it might not sounds as the approach you're describing, aren't shared_examples/shared_contexts a good match here ? unsure it'll speed up or not; but at least would reduce the codebase

Comment: My company is going through a similar process. I would recommend considering fixtures. There are definitely some hefty "cons" to using them (such as having to maintain global lists), but they do let you seed data on a per-test basis very quickly.

Comment: Are you working with real images in your factories? That was a huge killer for one of our apps, and substituting that for mock images (like just bogus file names in Paperclip for example) saved ~10 minutes in build time.